# Switch between pages of Quartz plot window in R.app

Tags: r, macos

I'm asking this question solely so that I can publicly document for others an answer that I found by experimenting after I was unable to find a similar question.  (It's a simple answer, though not obvious to me, at least, but I don't expect upvotes.)

In R.app in OS X, plots appear by default in a Quartz window.  Using Lattice, at least, it's possible to create multiple "pages" in the window.  For example, if you pass `layout=c(10,5)` to Lattice's `xyplot` in an expression like this one,

```
xyplot(x ~ y | z, data=d, layout=c(10,5))
```

where z has 100 values, there will be 100 plot panels generated.  However, because the `layout` parameter specifies 50 panels, the first 50 panels appear in the plot window and are then immediately replaced by the second 50 plots.

How can one switch between these different "pages" of the plot window?

Answer (score 0):

Use AppleKey-rightarrow and AppleKey-leftarrow to switch between "pages" of the plot window.